# How do I remove elements from a 3D tensor with PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor with shape `torch.Size([4, 161, 325])`. How do I remove the first element along dim=2 so that the resulting tensor has a shape of `torch.Size([4, 161, 324])`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use simple slicing,

```py
>>>a = torch.randn(4, 161, 325)
>>>b = a[:, :, 1:]
>>>b.shape
torch.Size([4, 161, 324])
```

Answer (score 2):

Do slicing

```py
t = torch.rand(4,161,325)

t = t[..., 1:]            # or t = t[Ellipsis, 1:] Here, Ellipsis indicate rest of dims
t.shape
torch.Size([4, 161, 324])
```